# Import task baseline start and finish date from MS Project into Excel by VBA

Tags: excel, ms-project, vba

Greets to all.

I'm facing this problema for two months ago without solution.

I need to get baseline start and finish dates from MS Project file into Excel by VBA, a piece of algorith that works is like this:

```
Set Prj = MSProject.Application
Dim tarea As Task

For Each tarea In Prj.ActiveProject.Tasks


Select Case BL

Case "BL0"
    StartD = CDate(Format(tarea.BaselineStart, "dd/mm/yyyy"))
    EndD   = CDate(Format(tarea.BaselineFinish, "dd/mm/yyyy"))

Case "BL1"
    StartD = CDate(Format(tarea.Baseline1Start, "dd/mm/yyyy"))
    EndD   = CDate(Format(tarea.Baseline1Finish, "dd/mm/yyyy"))

Case "BL2"
    StartD = CDate(Format(tarea.Baseline2Start, "dd/mm/yyyy"))
    EndD   = CDate(Format(tarea.Baseline2Finish, "dd/mm/yyyy"))

Case "BL3"
    StartD = CDate(Format(tarea.Baseline3Start, "dd/mm/yyyy"))
    EndD   = CDate(Format(tarea.Baseline3Finish, "dd/mm/yyyy"))
...
```

... and so until BL10; but this code is extremly inefficient and takes much more time to import dates when Project file has more than two thousand task lines.

I tried solution I found in next link to write just one line of code for different baselines https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/c964e627-079e-4296-9e5c-b7c82900d982/project-2010-standard-vba-export-to-excel-latest-baseline?forum=project2010custprog, but there is a little difference in results,

```
StartD = tarea.Baseline3Start --> StartD = 11/06/2014 07:00:00 a.m.

StartD = tarea.GetField(Application.FieldNameToFieldConstant("Baseline" & "3" & "Start", pjTask)) --> StartD = "wdn 11/06/14"
```

With second instruction vba does not get the exactly baseline date, it gets the field value as it is showed in MS Project and I can not convert this last result in a valid date value into Excel

I have also tried with Eval() and Evaluate() functions to write a general code to get this dates

```
BLstring = "tarea.Baseline" & "3" & "Start"
Eval(BLstring) --> Error 2409
```

It is understandable because this command is not a native Excel function

Is there any way I can get these dates without to use `Select case` sentence?
Or, may be, Is there a way to execute a string as MS Project outer command to get those dates?

Any idea will be much help for me.

EDIT #0: Finally, after two months of slowly and painful suffering, I have found out a solution.

Andrew Eversight Solution's does not work for me because it takes same method to get value from MSProject... It looks for PjFiel enumeration value (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff867782(v=office.15).aspx) which it is 188744184, to get field task value:

```
StartD = tarea.GetField(Application.FieldNameToFieldConstant("Baseline" & "3" & "Start", pjTask)) --> StartD = "wdn 11/06/14"
```

It is equivalent to

```
StartD = Tsk.GetField(tsk_fld_BaselineStart) --> StartD = "wdn 11/06/14"
```

For both case I get field value by pjFiel number

```
FieldNameToFieldConstant("Baseline" & "3" & "Start", pjTask) = 188744184
tsk_fld_BaselineStart = pjTaskBaseline3Start = 188744184
```

`tarea.GetField` instructions does the rest and result is the same `( "wdn 11/06/14" )`

As Rachel Hettinger said, GetField method always returns a string and, for some reason I don't look to understand, CDate does not convert this result into a valid date value.

Change application default date format, as Rachel Heetinger says, it is not reliable at this point, I don't want to modify any Project file (at this moment).

I can get correct value by using CallByName:

```
BLstring = "Baseline" & "3" & "Start"

For Each tarea In Prj.ActiveProject.Tasks

    StartD = CallByName(tarea, BLstring, VbGet)
    StartD_aux = tarea.Baseline3Start

...
```

Both instructions give same result `( 11/06/2014 07:00:00 a.m. )`

Dear Andrew and Rachel thank you for your fast answer and help on time.

Comment: FYI: When reading date values, it is helpful to change the `Application.DefaultDateFormat` to a format easily converted to a date (e.g. pjDate_mm_dd_yyyy). Just be sure to change it back to whatever the user had.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Performance is never going to be great when you've got a couple of thousand lines, but I can show you what I do, which is kind of a combination of the two.

First, you use the select case statement to get the name of the field you want to use before you start looping through the tasks:

```
Dim tsk_fld_BaselineStart As PjField
Dim tsk_fld_BaselineFinish As PjField

Select Case str_BaselineDestFieldSet

    Case "Baseline"
        tsk_fld_BaselineStart = pjTaskBaselineStart
        tsk_fld_BaselineFinish = pjTaskBaselineFinish
    Case "Baseline1"
        tsk_fld_BaselineStart = pjTaskBaseline1Start
        tsk_fld_BaselineFinish = pjTaskBaseline1Finish
    Case "Baseline2"
        tsk_fld_BaselineStart = pjTaskBaseline2Start
        tsk_fld_BaselineFinish = pjTaskBaseline2Finish

'... and so on

End Select
```

Having got these fields captured in variables, when you loop through the tasks you don't have to perform that enormous select case statement, or convert a string to a field value, as it's already done:

```
Dim Tsk As Task
Dim StartD As Date
Dim EndD As Date

For Each Tsk In ActiveProject.Tasks

    StartD = CDate(Tsk.GetField(tsk_fld_BaselineStart))
    EndD = CDate(Tsk.GetField(tsk_fld_BaselineFinish))

    Debug.Print "Task """ & Tsk.Name & """ starts " & StartD & " and ends " & EndD

Next Tsk
```

Make sure you explicitly declare StartD and EndD as date variables, as that may be why you're getting the wrong format back. That's not a problem I've experienced before. 
**UPDATE 11/11:** Rachel has clarified this point in the comments - code above has been updated to include CDate function on the dates.

If this is going to be regularly used on large projects, it may be worth implementing a progress bar to show the user that it is progressing during execution, as even with this performance enhancement, it could take some time to run.

Comment: FYI: The `GetField` method always returns a string, so it should be explicitly converted to a date.

Comment: More specifically, `GetField` returns dates in the format displayed in the UI, so `Application.DefaultDateFormat` should be changed to a format easily converted to a date (e.g. pjDate_mmmm_dd_yyyy). Just be sure to change it back to whatever the user had.